# Java Replace String with a variable text

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a document with many string like this:

```
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://example.com"/>
```

where http://example.com is not a constant value, it change every time.
The string must become:

```
<process:valueType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">http://example.com</process:valueType>
```

How can i do in java?

Comment: with string methods and regex, what have you tried?

Comment: i don't know how to save a value in regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
result = result.replaceAll("(<rdf:type rdf:resource=\"([^<]*)\"/>)", "<process:valueType rdf:datatype=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI\">$2</process:valueType>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use lookbehind to find `rdf:datatype` and select everything other than `"` which is actually the end of the value, something like this:

```
(?<=datatype=\")[^\"]*
```

you can do that with lookahead to:

```
(?<=datatype=\").*(?=\")
```